# How can I get the spacing to be equal?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I run this code there is a line between the 1st and 4th box. I'm using a flexbox. I wanted to make two rows of three items, but there's a line of space that I can't get rid of. I've tried everything that I could think of, but nothing is working. I've read up on the spacing, but nothing is working. Any ideas on this issue?

```
            <div class="projects">
            <h1 id="project" class="pro">Projects</h1>
            <div class="flex-container">

            <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex  justify-content-center d-inline align-content-center">
                  <div class="row " >
                     <div class="col-6 col-sm-2" >

                      <div class="one" style="width: 285px; height: 275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div> </div> </div>


                       <div class="two"style="width: 299px; height: 275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t2">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                            </div>

                        </div> </div> 
                        </div></div>

                        <div class="three "style="width:285px; height:275px;  ">
                                <div class="flip-card">
                                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                                  <div class="flip-card-front t3">
                                    <img class="light" src="light.png">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                    <p>We love that guy</p>
                                </div>

                            </div> </div> 
                            </div></div>




                            <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center d-inline  ">

                          <div class="row "> 

                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-2" >



                       <div class="four"style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t4">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>

                          </div> </div> 
                          </div></div>





                        <div class="five"style="width: 299px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t5">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png" >
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div></div></div> 

                        <div class="six"style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t6 ">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                          </div></div></div></div></div>


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

      </div>
```

```
CSS

.flip-card, .one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 280px;
    height: 275px;
    /*border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;*/
    perspective: 1000px; 


}


  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  /* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container*/ 
  .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  /* Position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing)*/ 
  .flip-card-front, .t3,.t5 {
    background-color:white;
    color: black;
   background-position: top 15px;

  }

   .flip-card-front.t2 ,.t4,.t6 {
    background-color: rgb(248, 122, 4);
    color: black;


  }

  /* Style the back side */
  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  /*@media screen and (max-width:959px){
  }

/*END FLIP*/
.projects{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width:100%;
height:680px;
display:block;}


.row{
    justify-content:space-between;
    display:block;



}


I want the boxes to have equal spacing.



.flip-card, .one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 280px;
    height: 275px;
    /*border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;*/
    perspective: 1000px; 

  
}


  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  /* Do a horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container*/ 
  .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  /* Position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing)*/ 
  .flip-card-front, .t3,.t5 {
    background-color:green;
    color: black;
   background-position: top 15px;
  
  }
  
   .flip-card-front.t2 ,.t4,.t6 {
    background-color: rgb(248, 122, 4);
    color: black;
  
  
  }
  
  /* Style the back side */
  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  /*@media screen and (max-width:959px){
  }

/*END FLIP*/
.projects{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width:100%;
height:680px;
display:block;}


.row{
    justify-content:space-between;
    display:block;
    

    
}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <div class="projects">
            <h1 id="project" class="pro">Projects</h1>
            <div class="flex-container">
            
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex  justify-content-center d-inline align-content-center">
                  <div class="row ">
                     <div class="col-6 col-sm-2" >
        
                      <div class="one" style="width: 285px; height: 275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div> </div> </div>
                
                      
                       <div class="two"style="width: 299px; height: 275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t2">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div> </div> 
                        </div></div>
            
                        <div class="three "style="width:285px; height:275px;  ">
                                <div class="flip-card">
                                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                                  <div class="flip-card-front t3">
                                    <img class="light" src="light.png">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="flip-card-back">
                                    <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                    <p>We love that guy</p>
                                </div>
                              
                            </div> </div> 
                            </div></div>
                
                          
                       
                       
                            <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center d-inline  ">
                
                          <div class="row "> 

                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-2" >
                
                
                    
                       <div class="four"style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t4">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                            
                          </div> </div> 
                          </div></div>


                          

            
                        <div class="five"style="width: 299px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t5">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png" >
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div></div></div> 
                              
                        <div class="six"style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
                            <div class="flip-card">
                            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                              <div class="flip-card-front t6 ">
                                <img class="light" src="light.png">
                              </div>
                              <div class="flip-card-back">
                                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                                <p>We love that guy</p>
                              </div>
                          </div></div></div></div></div>
                       
                            
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your code running correctly because yours is not very well formatted. If what I've got running in the snippet isn't correct, are you able to edit your question to remove the duplicated code and get the snippet running?

Comment: I got everything working properly thanks to the answer below. I know my code isn't up to par, but it runs now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a vertical line between the second and third column. I removed that by removing the width on .flip-card in this snippet.

```css
.flip-card,
.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 275px;
  /*border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;*/
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container*/

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing)*/

.flip-card-front,
.t3,
.t5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  background-position: top 15px;
}

.flip-card-front.t2,
.t4,
.t6 {
  background-color: rgb(248, 122, 4);
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/*@media screen and (max-width:959px){
  }

/*END FLIP*/

.projects {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 680px;
  display: block;
}

.row {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="projects">
  <h1 id="project" class="pro">Projects</h1>
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex  justify-content-center d-inline align-content-center">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">

          <div class="one" style="width: 285px; height: 275px;">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img class="light" src="light.png">
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <h1>John Doe</h1>
                  <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                  <p>We love that guy</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="two" style="width: 299px; height: 275px;">
          <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front t2">
                <img class="light" src="light.png">
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                <p>We love that guy</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="three " style="width:285px; height:275px;  ">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front t3">
              <img class="light" src="light.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
              <h1>John Doe</h1>
              <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
              <p>We love that guy</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex align-content-center justify-content-center d-inline  ">

      <div class="row ">

        <div class="col-6 col-sm-2">



          <div class="four" style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front t4">
                  <img class="light" src="light.png">
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <h1>John Doe</h1>
                  <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                  <p>We love that guy</p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>





        <div class="five" style="width: 299px; height:275px;">
          <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front t5">
                <img class="light" src="light.png">
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                <p>We love that guy</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="six" style="width: 285px; height:275px;">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front t6 ">
              <img class="light" src="light.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
              <h1>John Doe</h1>
              <p>Architect &amp; Engineer</p>
              <p>We love that guy</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```